# iterate the loop and set a new value based on the conditional check - java

Tags: java, collections, foreach

I want to create a condition such that if the products have the same model, i want to set `newID`'s (A, B, C). Below table is the sample data which i'm returning as a `List<MyDTO>` when `getAllListValue()` method is called.

sample data:

```
pID    prodName  Model    Year 
10       PN1      ABX      1999
11       PN2      ABX      1999
12       PN3      ABX      2000
13       PN4      XP       2002
14       PN5      xP       2003
15       PN6      HP       2006
16       PN7      LX       2008
17       PN8      LX       2009
```

- For `PN1` and model `ABX` i want to set `newID` as A.
- For `PN2` and model `ABX` i want to set `newID` as B.
- For `PN3` and model `ABX` i want to set `newID` as C
- For `PN4` and `XP` - set `newID` as A
- For `PN5` and `XP` - set `newID` as B
- For `PN6` and `HP` - set `newID` as A
- ..

sample code:

```
public class MyDTO {
    private String pID;
    private String productName;
    private String model;
    private String year;
    private String newID;
    // getter & setter
}

public class UseLoop {
    //logic
    List<MyDTO> dtoList = getAllListValue();
    //here i want to iterate the list and set the newID (A,B,c) for the products with same model
    for(MyDTO dto : dtoList) {   
        //here how can i compare with previous object and assign the newID if the product has the same model.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but if your sample data resides in a sql database then why not do it in the sql side, otherwise please explain your question better

Comment: What if number of elements with same model is greater then letters in alphabet?

Comment: No, it will be upto 4 elements for the same models maximum@tsolakp

Comment: Sort by (model, prodname). A for-loop. A variable char c='A'. On model change reset to 'A'. On next element ++c;

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `Map<String, Character>` wich keys are model names and values are incremented characters for new ids.

```
Map<String, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
List<MyDTO> dtoList = getAllListValue();
for (MyDTO dto : dtoList) {
    // put 'A' in the map if the model name is not present yet, 
    // increment character otherwise
    Character c = map.merge(dto.getModel(), 'A', (k, v) -> (char) (v + 1));
    dto.setNewID(c.toString());
}
```

This will produce something like:

```
MyDTO{pID='10', productName='PN1', model='ABX', year='1999', newID='A'}
MyDTO{pID='11', productName='PN2', model='ABX', year='1999', newID='B'}
MyDTO{pID='12', productName='PN3', model='ABX', year='2000', newID='C'}
MyDTO{pID='13', productName='PN4', model='XP', year='2000', newID='A'}
MyDTO{pID='14', productName='PN5', model='XP', year='2003', newID='B'}
MyDTO{pID='15', productName='PN6', model='HP', year='2006', newID='A'}
MyDTO{pID='16', productName='PN7', model='LX', year='2008', newID='A'}
MyDTO{pID='17', productName='PN8', model='LX', year='2009', newID='B'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using Java streams with custom collector:

```
    list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy( //group by model
            dto -> dto.getModel().toLowerCase(),

            Collector.of( () -> new int[1], //initial count for each group
                          (count, dto) -> {
                                              //count of 1 corresponds to A, 2 to B and so on
                                              dto.setNewID( String.valueOf((char) (count[0] + 65) ) ); 
                                              //increment count for each group
                                              count[0] += 1; 
                                          }, 
                          (count1, count2) -> {
                                              //combine counts for each group
                                              count1[0] += count2[0]; 
                                              return count1;
                                          }
                          )
            )
     );
```